# hslider prevent keyboard event

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4

Creating a sound slider, I want to prevent user from accidentally click End or Home button in HSlider for safety reason. I have override skinned for HSlider thumb and track. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, listen for keyboard events (keydown/ keyup) in the capture phrase and if the user presses either of those buttons, stopPropogation.